# Are C API more problematic than standard inputs SMTLIB2 for z3?

Tags: z3, smt

I'm completely new to z3. I wonder what the difference is between the two inputs, Are C API more problematic than standard inputs SMTLIB2 for z3? I would appreciate it if you could answer_(:з」∠)_

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "problematic." You'd use the C-API if you want to integrate z3 into a C/C++ based framework. You'd use SMTLib if you want a common language understood by many solvers, not just z3. So, it really depends on what your goals are.

If you're just experimenting with it, I'd advise using an interface in a higher level language like Python, as it is much easier to get started. SMTLib is generally not intended for human consumption, but rather generated by other programs. Only use the C/C++ API if you have some other requirement that requires you to stay in C/C++.

Long story short, it really depends on what your goal is; if you tell us more about what your use case is, we can recommend something more specific.

Comment: I need to make a tool for verifying programs, like stainless.  Using the c API is more convenient for development but I am worried that the API will bring some problems that I won't encounter with smtlib. I'm not sure if I made it clear, thanks very much

Comment: The C API is rock-solid. Actually, most of the other language API's are built on-top of the C-API. Of course it is harder to use, compared to other bindings, but it gives access to every single part of z3 directly. If the rest of your verification environment is going to be written in C, then by all means use the C API of z3.